# Sharepoint Online WebParts and TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, sharepoint, web-parts, sharepoint-online

in the past I created a site in sharepoint 2013 which I now would like to implement as a Sharepoint Online WebPart. I have been reading a researching a bit, and I've found that WebParts are created using TypeScript. Is that truly the only option I have to build the WebPart? Will all of the functions I used in JavaScript be implementable in TypeScript? Is there a site that you would recommend I use to learn TypeScript?

Thank you so much in advanced!

Comment: Anything that can be implemented in JavaScript can be implemented in TypeScript - the latter is a superset of the former. In regards to your last query, recommendations of learning resources are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

"You can choose to reuse your existing scripts. Even though the SharePoint Framework encourages using TypeScript, you can use plain JavaScript and gradually transform it to TypeScript". While existing scripts may not work 100% as SPFx solutions are packaged as JavaScript modules and load asynchronously. Check Reuse existing scripts section of below official guideline.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/migrate-script-editor-web-part-customizations

Here is a good resource for you.

[TypeScript Deep Dive](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/getting-started.html)

Answer (score 0):

Developing web part with new SharePoint framework is much easier to develop and debug. MS has encounter most of the hectec developers issues. I would recommend to use  SharePoint Framework

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment

it is easy to grab the framework info as it is open source and render time is much faster.Coolest thing is it can easily bind with TFS and reuse of component is 100%.

Another advance topic in sharepoint framework is to bundling in project which most of the developers neglecting in big org. It is to load external js files on run time at once for a website. 
i.e. If you have 4 webpart which are developed by different team , they can easily sync and used one time external Js loaded file on the website.

It is good approach. I tried to justify your answer with my experience. I hope it may help you.